# Three problems with Facebook login

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have installed the code i have found on facebook App and it works, but i have some problems:

1- I am using opencart theme, when i login in my Admin there, i CAN'T see my fb login logo on my website, it disapear. when i logout from my Admin it comes back. Why is it related to my Admin, my admin is not relevant in such case? What is relevantis the CUSTOMER LOGIN on my website.

2- There is no LOGOUT link near the facebook login logo, when my customer login in his fb account he can't logout, he needs to logout from facebook website itself.

3- I need to delete the message under the facebook login button, i have this message: "Be the first to login with facebook".... How can i delete this text?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. To my knowledge, OpenCart admins are still regular users. Since you're already logged in as the admin, there's no need to log in and thus the log in button isn't shown.
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/, enable "autologoutlink"
3. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/, disable "show-faces"

Comment: Thank you so much that was helpful!
I just want to tell you, there is no autologoutlink in my code.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to add it and set it to true.

Comment: You are responding so fast! WOW :-) That impressed me. thank you

Comment: Sorry for annoying!
I have added the autologout line and it doesn't work

This is how my code looks like:

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=573979636002115";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms=""></fb:login-button>